# C, Printing more than one integer from a linked list

Tags: c, printing, integer, linked-list

I'm very new to C, so I'm not totally sure what's the matter. I can't figure out how to print more than a single integer value in a function.

add function:

```
void add(char *name,int id,int copies)
{
/* Pointer to next item */
struct list *newAlbum;

newAlbum = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); 
strcpy((*newAlbum).name, name);  // Set album name
newAlbum->id = id;
newAlbum->copies = copies;
newAlbum->pNext = pFirst; 
pFirst = newAlbum;
}
```

show function:

```
void show()
{   
system("clear");
struct list *current_node;
current_node = pFirst;
while(current_node != NULL)
{   
    printf("Album #%d \n",current_node->id);
    printf("Album Name: %s \n",current_node->name);
    printf("Album Copies:%d \n",current_node->copies);
    printf("\n");
    current_node=current_node->pNext;
}
}
```

My program prints out the current_node->id as if it were current_node->copies, and current_node->copies is printed out as 134516043, which is obviously, wrong.

I think I must be passing something wrong to the function or something, but I can't figure it out. Any tips?

I call the function add like this:

```
add(name,id,copies);
```

The list is as so:

```
 /* THE LIST */
 struct list{
    char name[52];
    int id;
    int copies;
    int sold;
    struct list* pNext;
};
struct list *pFirst = NULL;
```

I call the function with user input with this piece of code:

```
printf("Enter the name of the new album. \n");
scanf("%s",&name);
printf("Enter the album id. \n");
scanf("%d",&id);
printf("Enter number of copies. \n");
scanf("%d," &copies);
// Pass data to add()
add(name,id,copies);
```

Comment: What is the definition of `struct list`? (In particular, what is the type of `name`?)

Comment: Sorry about that. Added.

Comment: what is the value of `copies` when calling `add`? Have you tried with literals instead, to do checking (in case the variable has the wrong value), i.e. `add("blah", 3, 8);`?

Comment: It works flawlessly if I use literals. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong though, obviously something with user input yes, but what exactly I don't know. I've added the code calling the function.

Comment: Nevermind. You should answer as a question rather than as a comment so I can set it as accepted answer. The literals thing really helped. :)

Comment: So what _was_ the problem? A case of buffer overrun?

Comment: It was a simple mistake on my part, something that I couldn't find until I tested with literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that you've shown is OK, as long as you don't pass an album name to `add()` which is longer than 51 characters.  If you do, you'll get very weird output, and possibly a crash.

To guard against this, you should use a length-limited copy - for example:

```
void add(char *name,int id,int copies)
{
    /* Pointer to next item */
    struct list *newAlbum;

    newAlbum = malloc(sizeof *newAlbum);
    if (newAlbum) {
        snprintf(newAlbum->name, sizeof newAlbum->name, "%s", name);  // Set album name
        newAlbum->id = id;
        newAlbum->copies = copies;
        newAlbum->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = newAlbum;
    }
}
```

(note that `sizeof *newAlbum` is a little better than `sizeof(struct list)`, since the former is "obviously correct" when reading the line - it will still be corret if the type of `newAlbum` is ever changed).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see wrong here is that you don't check the length of `name`.  You should use:

`strncpy(newAlbum->name, 52, name);`

This will prevent overrunning the `name` buffer.

Comment: The arguments to `strncpy()` are mixed. It should be `strncpy(newAlbum->name, name, 52);`

Comment: It also potentially leaves `newAlbum->name` unterminated (in the same situation where there would have been an overrun before).  Not as much garbage in, but still garbage out.